# В репозитории весь проект находится в master. Как перенести его в отдельную ветку, чтобы можно было сделать merge request в master?

Tags: git, gitlab

У меня есть задача, под которую мне выделили отдельный репозиторий. Я с самого начала не задумался о том, как буду отправлять её на ревью и делал всё в ветке master.
Теперь, как я понимаю, мне нужно следующее:  сделать ветку от мастера, а в мастере всё удалить.
Таким образом станет возможно сделать merge request в master.
В мастере нужно оставить .git и README.md.

Я верно понимаю процесс? Что-то нужно ещё?

Используется Gitlab.

Comment: Если в мастере немного коммитов (изначально или после squash), то по идее можно перенести через cherry-pick. Тут вообще многое зависит от того, пушили ли вы изменения в репозиторий или просто локальные коммиты.

Comment: Пушил в репозиторий. Коммитов очень много.

Comment: Вероятно, вам стоит обсудить это с командой и ревьюером, что лучше делать, т.к. коммиты через `push -f` вещь, которая не особо практикуется в командах и вам стоит обсудить это именно с коллегами, с которыми работаете, а не просто узнать все возможные способы выхода из ситуации. Они вам по крайней мере и согласуют тот или иной вариант. Например, если бы ко мне бы пришли с таким вопросом - я бы сказал "пересоздадим заново репозиторий, а коммиты сделаешь заново". Жестко, но зато можно понять необходимость планировать заранее.

Comment: Master это всего лишь указатель на коммит. Создаёте новую ветку на последнем коммите. А указатель master сбрасываете на нужный коммит.

Comment: @AK, `"пересоздадим заново репозиторий, а коммиты сделаешь заново"` — зачем же «заново»? в локальном хранилище-то все коммиты на месте. их можно экспортировать как набор патчей (`$ man git-format-patch`), как bundle (`$ man git-bundle`), наверно, ещё как-нибудь. а если сохранять историю нет необходимсти — так вообще просто diff+apply (не говоря уж про банальный cp -r).

Comment: @AlexR. Как изящно и просто! Отличная идея!

Answer (score 0):

На основе идеи @AlexR из комментариев.

Допустим у нас есть репозиторий с тремя коммитами:

```
C:\temp\1>git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

C:\temp\1>git log
commit 8607b728c12f11dd45aef65cf79e5e6009d08e3b (HEAD -> master)
Author: A K <AK@server.ru>
Date:   Fri May 7 17:31:44 2021 +0300

    Add file B

commit a55a094c4d4f47f87d70823d1780ea5cb9831fd7
Author: A K <AK@server.ru>
Date:   Fri May 7 17:31:21 2021 +0300

    Add file A

commit 879e28c46f87c34ff4ed4099aaf5a6e5ebb5e4ab
Author: A K <AK@server.ru>
Date:   Fri May 7 17:30:54 2021 +0300

    Add empty .gitignore

C:\temp\1>
```

И мы хотим коммиты с файлами A и B оставить в отдельной ветке feature1.

Тогда делаем две простых операции.

Во-первых, создадим ветку feature1:

```
C:\ak2m\1>git checkout -b feature1
Switched to a new branch 'feature1'

C:\ak2m\1>git status                                                                                                    
On branch feature1                                                                                                      
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Во-вторых перемотаем master на два коммита назад:

```
C:\ak2m\1>git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

C:\ak2m\1>git reset --hard HEAD~2
HEAD is now at 879e28c Add empty .gitignore
```

Всё!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]